# Redux: When removing specific element from array, it removes the last element instead

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im trying to remove an element from 'state' by using the filter function, which should remove the element from 'state' array at the index specified by 'action.index'. However it instead removes the last element from the 'state' array and I can't seem to figure out why it's doing it.

**/reducer.js**

```
import {
    ADD_ITEM,
    DELETE_ITEM,
} from './actions';

export default function addItems(state=[], action){
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_ITEM:
      return [
        ...state,
        action.item
      ]
    case DELETE_ITEM:
      return state.filter((_, i) => i !== action.index);
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

The above code works fine, it was a problem in another file that's removing the last element from the array.

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `action.index`? Maybe this has the wrong value for some reason.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/u9ma1c4p/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `splice` instead of filter which is more precise to remove an item at specific index.

```
return state.splice(action.index,1)
```

The second param '1' means remove 1 item starting from action.index.